# write a program that reads positive numbers from the user and stops if the user entered negative numbers

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python so I am having trouble doing my assignment. I need to create a program that adds an unspecified amount of positive numbers entered by the user, and the program will stop if the user entered a zero or a negative number. Then it prints out the total.
I think the problem with my code is that it doesn't loop. Please help me with this, thank you.

```
def again():
        c = 0  
        a = int(input("a"))
        if a >= 1:
                b = int(input("b"))
                while a and b >= 1:
                        if b >= 1:
                                c += (a + b)
                                print("Result",c)
                                again()
                                break
                        if a >= 0 and b >= 0:
                                break
again()
```

Comment: "*I think the problem with my code is that it doesn't loop*" Probably - can you make an attempt at adding this loop yourself? We aren't here to do your coursework *for* you. See [ask]

Comment: `a  and b >= 1` is not the same as `a >= 1 and b >= 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic and `syntax` has some errors and it's hard to follow. Hope this code snippet below can help you:

```
def again():
    # ask user to input a number:
    total = 0   # to sum up all entering numbers...
   
    
    while True:
        x = int(input('Please enter a positive number, or zero/negative to "Exit": '))

        if x > 0:  total += x

        elif x <= 0:  # see negative number
            print(f' total: {total} ')
            break

        
    
again()
```

running (and input number)

```
Please enter a positive number, or negative to "Exit": 1
Please enter a positive number, or negative to "Exit": 2
Please enter a positive number, or negative to "Exit": 3
Please enter a positive number, or negative to "Exit": 4
Please enter a positive number, or negative to "Exit": 5
Please enter a positive number, or negative to "Exit": -1
 total: 15
```

Comment: Doesn't work for 0. because elif check should be `x <= 0`, or more simply just make it an else clause then 2nd condition check is not needed.

Comment: Hello! The code above works, but I have a question, what does this code do?       
 print(f' total: {total} ')

Comment: Is that your asking for - >" Then it prints out the total. " in the Question?  You can read more about `f-string` format here -https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Answer (score -1):

Just put your "again()" function in a while loop, like this:

```
while True:
    again()
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: It didn't downvote --but my guess for the downvote is the posted function `again` has fundamental errors and can't be savaged by enclosing in a loop.  Additionally, your while loop will never exit.